# Quota utilities

Tags: files, application, quota

Are there any **command line** utilities that make it easier to read quotas (e.g. showing percentages,  approximate size in MB, etc.). Perhaps something like what [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) does for `top`, but for quota?

Comment: As an aside, I discourage enabling quotas on Linux/Unix because of the excessive overhead and additional maintenance required.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried webmin (www.webmin.com) - they've a disk quota module (http://download.webmin.com/download/modules/quota.wbm.gz)